# ListView / DataGrid with multiple rows in cell

Tags: wpf, listview, datagrid

I would like to make same ListView / DataGird like the following:

[image]

First: I am not sure if it's a ListView or a DataGrid, how can I know?
Second: How can I do that? (AS you can see, there's Icon in the first cell, and the second one is splitted to 3 rows > Name of device, Driver of device and Status of device. The third cell with the volume meter doesnt metter).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to H.B., If you just want to display without selection etc, use an `ItemsControl`: 
[ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx)

Comment: ItemsControls do not have have selection though, so depending on requirements this may or may not be a good idea...

Comment: Better solution for my purposes. Don't need to select each cell individually  but complete row. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a `ListView`, `ListBox` or `DataGrid`, as there are no headers a ListBox might be easiest.

Just create a [`ItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) with a `Grid`, use [`SharedSizeGroups`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup.aspx) to make the columns the same size, in the second column add another Grid with three rows for the text.

---

A `ListView` in combination with a `GridView` however would provide columns already, so you just need to create a Grid in the second column, you could style the headers to be collapsed.

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
```

`GridView` example (used as `ListView.View`):

```
<GridView>
    <GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Width="64" Height="64" Source="{Binding Icon}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Manufacturer}" Foreground="Gray" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Status}" Foreground="Gray" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
</GridView>
```

Comment: Although your answer is more immersed, Bolu answer is better for my purposes. I don't need to select each cell individually but complete row. Therefore I marked Bolu solution as accepted. Thank you for your time and solution.

Comment: @Ron: I think you misunderstood, if you use a `ListBoxe` or `ListView` you *do* select the full row, `ItemsControls` on the other hand have **no selection whatsoever**.